# Xlwings module causes PyInstaller EXE to throw exception

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller, xlwings

I'm trying to freeze a simple Python 3.4 script called *test.py* using `pyinstaller`. The script imports version 0.7.0 of the `xlwings` module (which I installed via `pip`), and then print a message.

```
import xlwings
print("Fine!")
```

If I remove the `xlwings` import, then `pyinstaller test.py` generates an EXE (I'm on Windows 10) inside the *dist* folder that prints the "Fine" message and then exits. But, if I import the `xlwings` module, the command generates an EXE that prints this message and then quits (not printing the "Fine" message):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2226, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1191, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1161, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 389, in load_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "site-packages\xlwings\__init__.py", line 20, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2226, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1191, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1161, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 389, in load_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "site-packages\xlwings\_xlwindows.py", line 29, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2226, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1191, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1161, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 389, in load_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "site-packages\pandas\__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2226, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1191, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1161, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 573, in load_module
    module = loader.load_module(fullname)
  File "pandas\tslib.pyx", line 55, in init pandas.tslib (pandas\tslib.c:102924)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2226, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1191, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1161, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 389, in load_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "dateutil\zoneinfo\__init__.py", line 31, in <module>
  File "dateutil\zoneinfo\__init__.py", line 24, in getzoneinfofile
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'C:\\Users\\OrangeFlash81\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\_MEI102122\\dateutil\\zoneinfo'
test returned -1
```

I'm aware that `cx_Freeze` has issues when `dateutil` is imported, and this error message references `dateutil`. Does `pyinstaller` suffer the same issues, and if so, how can I resolve them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not exactly a solution, but I decided to switch to using the `XLRD` module, which does everything I need and works flawlessly with `pyinstaller`; changing `xlwings` code to use `XLRD` isn't too difficult either.

Comment: cx_Freeze had an issue with xlwings v0.7.0 that has been solved with v0.7.1 - potentially this resolved the issue that you saw with PyInstaller also.

Comment: @FelixZumstein Thank you - I'll update `xlwings` and try again.